# C++ Inheritance : Base attributes over various derived objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I'm currently learning about C++ Inheritance, so if this question is a dumb one, I apologize in advance.

Implementing this scenario:

1. A super class has a color attribute, which can be any color (let's assume color is represented by an integer).
2. Let's assume I have an initialization of this super class, with the color red.
3. I am also going to initialize different objects of a sub-class which also share the color red.

My question is, is there any way that I can initialize this attribute color to red (or any color for that matter) and it would be automatically inherited by objects of it's sub-class, instead of setting the attribute to red every-time I initialize one of these objects?

Again apologies if I'm missing a basic concept here, but I can't seem to find anything online on this.

Pseudo-Code per request:

Super-class code:

```
class Shape {

    int color;

    Shape::Shape(int c) : color(c) { }  //constructor

}
```

Sub-Class code:

```
class Square {

    int length, width;

    Square::Square(int l, int w, int c)
    :    length(l),
         width(w),
         color(c)
    { }
}

class Circle {

    int radius;

    Square::Square(int r, int c)
    :    radius(r),
         color(c)
    { }
}
```

What I'm trying to say is that both square and circle need to have the same color, is there anyway (maybe from the super class? ) to declare this color (ex. red), and both shapes would have this color set the same?

Comment: You have a color attribute in base class *and* a color attribute in derived classes too ? A MVCE would be helpful.

Comment: no the color attribute is obviously getting inherited from the superclass

Comment: Please post a pseudo-code example of what you think things may look like. You're using the word "attribute," but there are a very large number of possible ways to implement an "attribute" (member-variable, virtual-member-function-with-default-implementation, etc). Also who is doing the initialization? (also: initialize *is* setting the value every time, just with a slightly different syntax)

Comment: @Logan so what's the problem ? The derived class obviously will have the same value as the base one.

Comment: Do you want something like `class RedShape : public Shape` where `RedShape`'s `Shape` object always has its color set to red, or do you want something like `Shape s(RED); Circle c; // c is automatically red`?

Comment: Please show some code and explain why you don't like it.

Comment: @MilesBudnek the 2nd option yes, an attribute in the super set to a specific value, and THAT specific value is set to the same attribute in the inherited classes.

Comment: I'm confused by your sample code. 1) Your shapes don't inherit from `Shape`, what is the intended inheritance here? 2) Your (presumed) sub-class constructors initialize the (presumed) super-class member. That can't happen.

Comment: The sub-classes inherit the color attribute from the super class, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Those two sub-classes don't have a super-class. Nothing in your code connects `Square` to `Shape`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish what you want with a static `default_color` that gets used when no color is explicitly specified, and gets set whenever a color is specified.

```
struct Shape {
    static int default_color;
    int color;
    Shape(int c) : color(c)
    {
        default_color = c;
    }
    Shape() : color(default_color) {}
};

Shape::default_color = BLACK;

struct Square : public Shape {
    int length, width;
    Square(int l, int w, int c)
    : Shape(c),
      length(l),
      width(w),
    { }

    Square(int l, int w)
    : length(l),
      width(w)
    { }
}

struct Circle : public Shape {
    int radius;
    Circle(int r, int c)
    : Shape(c),
      radius(r)
    { }

    Circle(int r)
    : radius(r)
    { }
}

int main()
{
    Square sq(2, 3, RED);
    Circle cir(10); // Automatically red, since that's
                       the last color explicitly specified
}
```

I would say this is a poor design though.  Global state like this makes it very easy to make mistakes.  You now have to think about the state of the entire program whenever you create a shape.  It would be better to simply create the `Circle` as `Circle cir(10, sq.color);`.  That makes it explicit what color your `Circle` is, and reduces cognitive load on the programmer.

Comment: I see. I was just exploring this concept out of curiosity and needed clarification. As for practical applications, yes I agree with you that it's poor practice and can prove destructive. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Prior to C++11, the primary way to do this would be as follows:

```
class baseClass
{ 
    int color;

    baseClass() { color = RED; }
};

class subClass : public baseClass
{
    subclass() { }
};
```

With C++11 and later, you can assign the default value in the class declaration:

```
class baseClass
{ 
    int color = RED;

    baseClass() { }
};
```

This would be inherited.

EDIT: As mentioned below, the default `baseClass` constructor is automatically called in this case.

Comment: You could also use an initializer list.

Comment: `:baseClass()` was never a requirement AFAIK.

Comment: @A.S.H You are absolutely correct. I blame my pneumonia. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between a class and an instance of a class. A class is something like a structure, according to which further instances will be created. A class is something like a description, an instruction how to build objects. Inheritance is related to classes, not to objects. As for fields, the inherited class has all the same fields from the parent class plus some new fields you may add.

A simple example for you:

```
class MyBase {
public:
    int color;
};

class MyChild : public MyBase {
public:
    double length;
}

int main() {
    MyBase myBaseObj;
    myBaseObj.color = 1;

    MyChild myChildObj;
    myChildObj.color = 2;
    myChildObj.length = 3.14;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there anyway (maybe from the super class? ) to declare this color (ex. red), and both shapes would have this color set the same?

In your posted example, yes. A super-class constructor can set its variables to whatever it wants to, for example:

```
Shape::Shape(int c) : color(7) { }  // 7 == RED
```

If `Shape` had that constructor defined, then instances of every subclass would represent red shapes.

This sample program prints 7, overriding the user's chosen color:

```
#include <iostream>

class Shape {
public:

    int color;

    Shape(int c) : color(7) { }  //constructor

};

class Square : public Shape {
public:

    int length, width;

    Square(int l, int w, int c)
    :    Shape(c),
         length(l),
         width(w)
    { }
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:

    int radius;

    Circle(int r, int c)
    :    Shape(c),
         radius(r)
    { }
};

int main() {
    Square q(4,8,0);
    std::cout << q.color << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I see, so virtually you can have a constructor which accepts multiple options for color right? Building on this, what would happen if one has multiple instances of the super class (Shape) with different colors set before the sub-classes are initialized, would their color attribute be set to the same color as the last initialization of the super class?

Comment: You can have as many instances of the super class as you want. The only super-class instance that matters to a specific instance of a sub class is the one that is contained within that sub-class instance.